# Need to help to convert string to hex bytes

Tags: java

I am programming in Java.  The program have a String as below.

```
String str = "byte."
```

Can the above string be converted to an array of hex bytes as below?

```
byte[] data = {0x62, 0x79, 0x74, 0x65};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you even looked at the API?

Comment: You didn't intend to put the . at the end, right?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as "hex bytes" and more than there are "decimal integers" vs "hex integers".

You can certainly convert a string to a byte array though. For example:

```
byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

The `UTF-8` part here is the name of the encoding to use - where an *encoding* is effectively a mapping between Unicode characters and bytes. (It's somewhat more complicated than that, but it's a good first approximation.)

There *is* a parameterless overload of `String.getBytes()` but I would *strongly* recommend that you don't use it - it will pick the platform default encoding, which is rarely a good idea.

You can also use an overload taking a `Charset`, which ends up being nicer in conjunction with a library such as [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), where you can write:

```
byte[] data = str.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
```

... so you no longer rely on a string representation.